# Broswers open localhost instead of remote server

Tags: linux, networking, dns, localhost

When I try to access my domain http://www.ylog.in , all browsers in my system opens localhost (Where I have Apache2) instead of my remote server hosted at heroku. But when I open the domain via proxy, it works fine.

Amazingly both

```
nslookup www.ylog.in


ping www.ylog.in
```

resolves to 127.0.0.1

My /etc/hosts contains no entries for www.ylog.in .

Operating System: Linux Mint 12
Name Servers : 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

PS: I remember that some day I have intentionally made the domain to resolve to 127.0.0.1 but I forgot what I did to achieve that. I should have made changes name server provided by registrar or made changes to /etc/hosts. But right now both doesn't contain any entries like that.

Comment: Can we get the complete output of a ping, the nslookup and `dig ylog.in`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no A record on Google's name server:

```
$ dig www.ylog.in @8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.9.3-rl.13207.22-P2-RedHat-9.9.3-5.P2.fc19 <<>> www.ylog.in @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 53820
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.ylog.in.           IN  A

;; Query time: 1298 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Fri Aug 23 15:14:43 IST 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 40
```

Most likely, your most recent change hasn't propagated yet. Wait a few days.

Comment: The problem resolved by itself. The most recent DNS change was made 72 hour before the occurrence of problem. DNS caches should be invalidated after 24 hours at maximum. Looks like GooglE DNS is deviating slightly from standards.